# How did the mixed-root "anticipātiō, anticipātiōnis" form?

Tags: etymology, morphology

I was considering the English word *anticipation* the other day, and wondered at how it ended up with a Greek prefix followed by a Latin root.<sup>1</sup> After a quick search I found that the word derives from *anticipātiō, anticipātiōnis* which also has this feature. Do we know anything about how this word was formed? Was the prefix first appropriated into the Latin language and made common as a Latin prefix? Or is there some other explanation?

---

<sup>1</sup> I found this [related question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4711/did-the-romans-ever-combine-greek-and-latin-morphemes), where my hypothesis finds support in Joonas' answer. But it still remains a hypothesis, not an answer, as this is a specific case, not a general question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me that [*anticipatio*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=anticipatio&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) comes from [*anticipare*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=anticipo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059), which in turn comes from [*antecapere*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=antecapio&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059).
If this line of thought is correct, it was originally the Latin prefix *ante-*, but the *-e-* was weakened into *-i-*.
The prefix *ante-* appears in several verbs, including *antecedere*, *anteponere*, and *antevertere*.

It is not unusual that vowels get weaker when words get longer by derivation, but cases where a short *-e-* becomes an *-i-* are harder to find.
Following a suggestion by sumelic in the comments, I found examples where *mille-* has turned into *milli-*: *milliformis*, *millimodus*, *millipeda*.
All other examples I found of *anti-* are of Greek origin, so *anticipatio* seems quite unique.

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense! I was actually wondering how the Greek prefix made sense semantically. But the Latin prefix *ante-* explains it. I suppose I am too quick to assume what is Greek, what is Latin!

Comment: Oddly enough, ἀντί and ante are cognates. They both come from *h₂énti, which has multiple senses, including "opposite" and "before". Thus Greek conserved one of these senses, whereas Latin conserved the other.

Comment: @ktm5124 I always assumed they were cognates, as they are so similar in many respects. Sometimes *ante* means "in front of" (cf. *Hannibal ante/ad portas*), which is not that far from "opposite". Now that I think of it, a comparison of *ante* and *ἀντί* would make an interesting question.

Comment: Yes, it might! Interesting that the two senses are related.

Comment: It seems that *millipeda* "millipede" was a variant form of *[millepeda](https://books.google.com/books?id=oQ3gAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA16-IA365&lpg=PA16-IA365&dq=%22millipeda%22+Latin+%22millepeda%22&source=bl&ots=gK5lq8jsMj&sig=8tifatneH47U_zybNRXGrwkgkRw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPo7nmscbXAhWKy4MKHfP5DW0Q6AEIKjAB#v=onepage&q=%22millipeda%22%20Latin%20%22millepeda%22&f=false).* That's not quite the same, but maybe a bit similar.

Comment: @sumelic It's certainly more similar than anything I could think of. A short *e* at the end of a prefix turning to an *i* sounds right. I'll see if I can think of something more...

Comment: @sumelic You answer looks very interesting! I will give it a closer look later. You should ask a separate question about translating Lundström's quote; that has proven to be an efficient way to figure out what exactly a Latin quote says.

Answer (score 4):

As Joonas said in his answer, the *anti-* found in *anticipāre* and *anticipātiō* seems to be merely a variant of the Latin adverb *ante*/prefix *ante-,* not a Greek prefix.

There seems to have been at least one more word that often had this variant of the prefix *ante-*: *[antistes](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dantistes),* which Lewis and Short say is from the verb *antisto,* a variant of *[ante-sto](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dantesto).* Apparently, scribes did fairly often replace the spelling *antistes* with *antestes,* but the spelling with "i" seems to be considered more standard or more common.

According to "[Aspects of the phonology and morphology of Classical Latin](http://real-d.mtak.hu/896/7/dc_1106_15_doktori_mu.pdf)" by András Cser,

> 8.2.1.7. *ante-*
>
> This prefix appears as *ante-* or *anti-* without any discernable regularity:
>
> (74) Words prefixed with *ante-/anti*
>
> antecellere 'surpass'
>   
> antecedere 'precede'
>   
> antesignani 'troops in front'
>   
> anteferre 'carry in front'
>   
> anticipare 'anticipate'
>   
> antistes 'high priest'
>
> [...] It would be interesting to see how the final vowel of *anti-/ante-* behaves in the environment of lowering before [r] (see 5.1.2.2), but this prefix does not combine with stems beginning with [r] at all.

(p. 150)

Using the PHI Latin Texts search, I was able to find an isolated example of *antilucanam* used in place of *antelucanam* in L. Iunius Moderatus Columella, De Re Rustica 11.2.4.1. This is mentioned in "Emendationes in Collumellam" by Vilelmus Lundström (in *[Eranos](https://books.google.com/books?id=-A4MAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=%22+antilucanam%22&source=bl&ots=l3YgTce9AF&sig=O9r8hSe8LEbzbpnSIbBuNM_EXPY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw1Y-r8cHaAhWo6IMKHW5FBucQ6AEITjAH#v=onepage&q=%22%20antilucanam%22&f=false),* 1907):

> XI, 2, 12 *antilucanam* hunc locum editurus scribendum curaui cum **S A**. Vix enim crediderim librarios *ante-* in *anti-,* quod iis alienum esset, mutauisse; contra *anti-* in *ante-* ut sponte mutarent, consuetudo facile persuadebat (cfr I, 10 *antestites* **S** m. pr., quod librarius exemplari suo diligentius inspecto ipse correxit). Quam ob rem si quis infra 2. 55 *antilucanis* (ubi *antelucanis* **S A R**) restituere uelit, equidem neque alteri dissuadere neque tamen ipse facere ausim. Nam inter -ĕ- et -ĭ- uacillare auctorem ipsum credo (cfr *beneuolentia* et *beniuolentia* sat multis locis).

Unfortunately, I can't read Latin well enough to give a translation of this text, but it seems to me that Lundström says here that it was more common for scribes to change *anti-* into *ante-* than vice versa, so he doesn't think that we can say for sure that *anti-* in *antilucanis* is just a scribal error (although Lundström also doesn't seem to feel that he can completely rule out that possibility).

Here are my guesses about possible factors that contributed to the change of *ante-* to *anti-* in *anticipāre* and *anticipātiō:*

### *e* and *i* are phonetically similar

Of course, *e* and *i* in Classical Latin were fairly similar phonetically, both being front non-low vowels. This may have made it easier in general for them to interchange. Another odd case of /i/ occurring where /e/ might be expected is ["decim" in words related to *decem*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5150/comparing-decem-and-decim).

In *anticipāre,* the following syllable also has *i,* so it seems possible to me that regressive assimilation might have played some role in the development of *ante* to *anti-* here. But it's very unclear to me.

### *i* is common in internal open syllables in Latin

In an open syllable that is not the first or last syllable of a word, a short vowel not followed by /r/ or a consonant cluster containing /r/ will often be /i/, because of processes of vowel reduction that occurred in older stages of Latin. In the time of Classical Latin, this reduction of short vowels in word-internal syllables to /i/ did not apply as an automatic, exceptionless rule. But the existence of this type of weakening may be relevant to the development of the *anti-* form used in *anticipāre.*

We see this kind of vowel reduction for example in the "cip" part of *anticipātiō,* and in the second part of a number of prefixed verbs such as *assideō* <  *ad-* +‎ *sedeō.* We also see "short i" as a vowel coming after the first element of a compound in words like *[artifex](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=artifex),* from *ars* and *facio.*

The use of "i" as a generic "linking vowel" in Latin compound words (e.g. "[altispex](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Daltispex)" and "[extispex](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dextispex)") may have provided some analogical basis for changing *ante-* to *anti-* in *anticipāre* (and, apparently, *antistes,* where the vowel isn't even in an open syllable).

A possibly similar variant is *mali-* in place of *male-* in the word *[maleficus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=maleficus);* Lewis and Short say that *malificus* occurs as a variant spelling used in manuscripts.

### Some words that are morphologically related to *ante* have *i*

Etymologically, the *e* in *ante* actually comes from *i,* and there are still remnants of this in some words: de Vaan says

> original *i* is still visible in *antiae,* in the inflexion of *antēs,* and in *antīquus.*

De Vaan also mentions the compounding form *antid-,* which he says is "probably on the analogy of *postid*".

I don't know if this is at all relevant to the use of "i" in *anticipāre,* but it seems vaguely possible.