# What do the future active participle "editurus" and the gerundive or gerund "scribendum" mean in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-translation, latin-to-english-translation, grammar-identification, participle

When I was trying to find information to answer [ktm5124's question about 
“anticipātiō, anticipātiōnis”](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5562/how-did-the-mixed-root-anticip%C4%81ti%C5%8D-anticip%C4%81ti%C5%8Dnis-form), I came across a passage that I am not advanced enough to understand fully. I'd like to ask for some help with the translation.

The following paragraph comes from "Emendationes in Collumellam" by Vilelmus Lundström (in *[Eranos](https://books.google.com/books?id=-A4MAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=%22+antilucanam%22&source=bl&ots=l3YgTce9AF&sig=O9r8hSe8LEbzbpnSIbBuNM_EXPY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw1Y-r8cHaAhWo6IMKHW5FBucQ6AEITjAH#v=onepage&q=%22%20antilucanam%22&f=false),* 1907):

> XI, 2, 12 *antilucanam* hunc locum editurus scribendum curaui cum **S A**. Vix enim crediderim librarios *ante-* in *anti-,* quod iis alienum esset, mutauisse; contra *anti-* in *ante-* ut sponte mutarent, consuetudo facile persuadebat (cfr I, 10 *antestites* **S** m. pr., quod librarius exemplari suo diligentius inspecto ipse correxit). Quam ob rem si quis infra 2. 55 *antilucanis* (ubi *antelucanis* **S A R**) restituere uelit, equidem neque alteri dissuadere neque tamen ipse facere ausim. Nam inter -ĕ- et -ĭ- uacillare auctorem ipsum credo (cfr *beneuolentia* et *beniuolentia* sat multis locis).

I'm having particular trouble understanding how to read the first sentence. My attempt so far:

```
XI, 2, 12 *antilucanam*  - "XI, 2, 12 *antilucanam*"
hunc locum               - "this place (here)"-acc.
editurus                 - m-s-nom. fut active part. of "edo" = "going to publish"?
scribendum               - acc. gerund or gerundive of "scribo" = "for writing"?
curaui                   - 1s-perf of "curo" = " I took care of"?
cum S A.                 - "with SA"
```

It seems to have the first person singular as the subject, with the main verb "curavi", but I don't understand the grammatical roles of the other words in the sentence.

I think I have the gist of the rest of the sentences, with a few difficult spots bolded below:

> I believe scribes very rarely changed *ante-* into *anti-,* which was alien to them; contrariwise **convention easily persuaded (?)** [***consuetudo facile persuadebat***] that they freely changed *anti-* into *ante-* (compare I, 10 *antestites* S **m. pr.**, **which I consider a scribe more diligently corrected himself by his copy** (?) [*quod librarius exemplari suo **diligentius** inspecto ipse correxit*]). And therefore, if anyone wants to restore below 2. 55 *antilucanis* (where *antelucanis* S A R), certainly I dare **neither to dissuade the one nor however do so [him?]self** [*neque alteri dissuadere neque **tamen ipse facere***]. For I believe the author himself vacillates between -ĕ- et -ĭ- (compare *beneuolentia* and *beniuolentia* in many places).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an editorial rule of thumb: 'The more difficult reading is to be preferred,' and in this case the author, Lundström, prefers *antilucanam* and *antilucanis*(line 4), when the other versions **S A,**  and (line 4) **S A** and **R** are in favour of the dictionary preference *antelucanus.*

> XI  2, 12 *antilucanam:* when preparing this locus for publication I
>   (curavi) gave special attention to the writing of **S** and **A**.

In this statement of the *Difficilius melius* principle, he uses a 1st person negative imperative: *vix* plus the perfect subjunctive.

> Let me not believe that copyists have changed *anti-* into *ante-,* which
>   would have been alien to them; By contrast, *ante-* into
>   *anti-*, common practice easily persuades *(imperfect habitual)* that they
>   might change spontaneously.  (compare...**source 'S'**...which the
>   copyist himself has corrected,  his own exemplar having been inspected
>   (ablative absolute)  more closely.)

The last two sentences are almost what you have written:

> ...if anyone should wish to replace the [difficult] antilucanis, with the
>   [easy] antelucanis, as **S A R** [do], I [supply *velim]* would not wish to dissuade that
>   'other person (dative),' but I would not, riskily, wish to do so myself.

Comment: Thank you! So in the third sentence, "ipse" can be translated as "myself", even though there is no accompanying first-person pronoun?

Comment: Yes, the nominative by default is the author.  By the way *scribendum* is ' written stuff' just as *legendum* is 'reading matter.'

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. So it is correct to say that "scribendum" is the object of "curaui" and "hunc locum editurus" is a subordinate, participial phrase?

Comment: Yes; Lundström is 'about to publish' or 'is in the process of preparing to publish on this locus, at the time when he pays special attention to the *scribendum* **A S**